# Updating "Receipt" comments on a Shopify Order using ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, shopify

I'm trying to update the `Receipt` attribute of an order using ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment

I'm doing this:

```
fulfill = ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment.find(351144XXXX, :params => 
{:order_id =>  426199XXXX})
joe = fulfill.receipt
joe.response_status = "Accepted"
joe.response_comment = "Your order was received by Yo Mama"
fulfill.save
```

It saves it, but the order doesn't keep the save.. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the receipt

```
joe = fulfill.receipt
joe.response_status = "Accepted"
joe.response_comment = "Your order was received by Yo Mama"
joe.save
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the values of `Receipt` and saving `Fulfillment`

replace

```
fulfill.save
```

with

```
joe.save
```